# Leaflet with maps offline

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I would like to know if it is possible to use the referenced leaflet on an offline map. I have a file of an .osm map but I don't know what to do to work or how to go on what I wanted would be something like this.

L.tileLayer('https://tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=', {maxZoom: 20});

L.tileLayer('my map locate', {maxZoom: 20});

Comment: Take a look at mbtiles. A `.map` file won't help since it contains raw data whereas Leaflet usually expects pre-rendered data.

Comment: If I understand what is needed. You may download all necessary tiles and than set `tileLayer` to point to place where tiles stored. More deatails https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#tilelayer